# Glide make ImageView wrap_content useless and no animatiion using target

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-glide

I'm load a picture using `Glide` in my project, but I found a strange thing. When I use `into(ImageView)`, the `ImageView` displays not the same with what when using `into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(centerImageView))`：

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/center_image_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

When I use :

```
String imageUrl = "http://7xlz1k.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/feedback-201604229711.png";
Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).into(centerImageView);
```

The ImageView's `wrap_content` doesn't work, it displays like this:
[image]

But when I use :

```
    Glide.with(this).load(imageUrl).asBitmap().into(new BitmapImageViewTarget(centerImageView));
```

The ImageView looks :

[image]

The image contained in the `imageUrl` is a 120*120 picture.

And when I use the `BitmapImageViewTarget`, the default animation doesn't work.

**Three questions:**

1. Why is there the difference between the two methods?
2. How can I make the ImageView's `wrap_content` useful when using the first method?
3. And How can I make the default animation enable when using the `BitmapImageViewTarget`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I will try give a solution for your second question:

> 2. How can I make the ImageView's wrap_content useful when using the first method?

I managed to make wrap_content working by adding adjustViewBounds to the ImageView's layout:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/center_image_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked for me by adding "adjustViewBounds". Have a great day sir:)

Answer (score 0):

My Glide version : 4.9.0

```xml
<!--  my ImageView:  -->
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

```java
    public static void showRoundedCornerImage(ImageView imageView, 
                       String url, int maxHeight,int maxWidth,int corner) {
        Context context = imageView.getContext();
        corner = OsUtils.dp2px(context, corner);
        maxHeight = OsUtils.dp2px(context, maxHeight);
        maxWidth = OsUtils.dp2px(context, maxWidth);

        Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .fitCenter()
                .transform(new RoundedCorners(corner))
                .override(maxWidth,maxHeight)// look here
                .into(imageView);
    }
```